# Unwanted help screen displayed in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: Unwanted help display (white bit)]

I have been fiddling with the code analysis settings, and obviously clicked something I ought not to have clicked, and now I have this rather obtrusive help display occupying half the screen. Is there any way to get rid of it? (Closing down and restarting doesn't.)

**Edit** Following the suggestions given, Windows->Reset Windows Layout doesn't get rid of the screen, but shutting down the machine does so, until using the Action pull-down while editing a ruleset causes it to reappear.

Comment: Might be an extension window gone haywire? Try Window -> Reset window layout. If it remains even after closing VS, it's running independently in the background (it looks like a browser window, actually), so you'd have to kill it with Task Manager (or log out/log in).

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for that. Restarting the machine has reduced it to a thin white strip across the bottom, which it will hopefully remain.

Comment: Were you playing exception settings? Also, can you please paste bit larger view of the dialog that do you see? Finally, is this VS2019 or VS2022?

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar I have got rid of the problem, but only by nuking the Visual Studio installation (I had 2015, 2017 and 2019, and had to get rid of them all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A temporary solution to this problem is to `restart the machine`.

You can try to repair it with these tools: [1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e) [2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-net-framework-repair-tool-is-available-942a01e3-5b8b-7abb-c166-c34a2f4b612a)